# Converting Data pipleine into Code Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, amazon-data-pipeline, continuous-delivery, aws-codepipeline

I have a data pipleine running in aws .
I can extract JSON out of it.
Is there any way i can convert this JSON into codepile line json or yaml ?

I have tried in CloudFormer but i could not found the option for Data pipeline .

Comment: Data pipeline is for data processing, whereas CodePipeline is for software release automation and continuous delivery. They have very different features and purposes. What's your use-case for converting one to the other?

Comment: @TimB yes it works differently .But i dont want to write Cloud Fomration templet ,instead i want to utilize the JSON that we get from the DataPipeline and write CloudFormation templet .